Why is the tf.keras.models.load_model building the model again?
ValueError: Sequential model 'sequential_2' has already been configured to use 
input shape (None, 224, 224, 3). You cannot build it with input_shape [None, 224, 224, 3]

def load_model(model_path):
  """
  Loads a saved model from a specified path.
  """

  tf.keras.config.enable_unsafe_deserialization()
  print(f"Loading saved model from: {model_path}")
  model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
  return model

loaded_1000_image_model = load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision/models/20241002-16491727887796-1000-images-mobilenetv2-Adam.h5')

I was expecting that it would load the model without any errors but for some reason it's giving a Value Error even thought I am not trying to rebuild or give any INPUT SHAPE again.

The only thing that was disabling this to run was not updating keras.

Was the model compiled before saving? If not, you should try compiling before saving. You can also try setting compile to false, and seeing if the compile step is where things are failing. you can also skip the "tf.keras.config.enable_unsafe_deserialization()" by setting safe_mode=False.
tf.keras.models.load_model(
    filepath, custom_objects=None, compile=True, safe_mode=True
)


def create_model(input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE, output_shape=OUTPUT_SHAPE, model_url=MODEL_URL):
model =  tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: hub.KerasLayer(MODEL_URL)(x)), # Layer 1
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=OUTPUT_SHAPE,
activation='softmax') # Layer 2
])
model.compile(
loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
metrics=['accuracy']
)
model.build(INPUT_SHAPE)
return model
my create_model function, idk the reason when I load the data it rebuilds

To answer your question, it does compile and then it is saved, and I am not trying to give it a list of new input shape as you can see my load model function, but this error persists even when i set compile=False
